Percona-xtradb cluster in docker swarm timed out after stack restart
Recently I created a stack with a docker-compose.yml to deploy in a docker swarm of 4 servers for percona-xtradb with etcd.
This is the docker-compose.yml:
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
version: '3.9'
services:

 percona_etcd:
  image: quay.io/coreos/etcd
  command:  etcd
  environment:
   - ETCD_DATA_DIR=/opt/etcd/data
   - ETCD_NAME=percona_etcd
   - ETCD_LISTEN_CLIENT_URLS=http://0.0.0.0:2379,http://0.0.0.0:4001
   - ETCD_ADVERTISE_CLIENT_URLS=http://percona_etcd:2379,http://percona_etcd:4001
   - ETCD_LISTEN_PEER_URLS=http://0.0.0.0:2380
   - ETCD_INITIAL_ADVERTISE_PEER_URLS=http://percona_etcd:2380
   - ETCD-INITIAL-CLUSTER=etcd0=http://percona_etcd:2380
   - ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER_STATE=new
   - ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER_TOKEN=percona-etcd-cluster
  networks:
   - overlay
  deploy:
   mode: replicated
   replicas: 1
  volumes:
   - percona_etcd:/opt/etcd/data

 percona:
  image: percona/percona-xtradb-cluster:8.0
  networks:
   - overlay
  environment:
   - DISCOVERY_SERVICE=tasks.percona_etcd:2379
   - CLUSTER_NAME=percona
   - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD='true'
  cap_add:
   - SYS_NICE
  deploy:
   mode: replicated
   replicas: 3
   endpoint_mode: vip
   placement:
    max_replicas_per_node: 1
    constraints:
     - node.labels.percona == true
  volumes:
   - percona_my_cnf_d:/etc/my.cnf.d
   - percona_data:/var/lib/mysql
   - percona_log:/var/log/mysql

networks:
 overlay:
  external: true
volumes:
 percona_my_cnf_d:
  driver: glusterfs
 percona_etcd:
  driver: glusterfs
 percona_log:
  driver: glusterfs
 percona_data:
  driver: local
  driver_opts:
   o: bind
   type: none
   device: /data/percona

When first I deployed the cluster did go up and connection to percona worked as should with replication.
Second day after a stack is stopped and started, the pecona-xtradb services does not get in contact with each other. I just receive in logs following:
ercona_percona.3.4nfwet49xkaf@6    | 2024-06-26T09:34:44.837454+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] (97a651ce-b4b8, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection to peer 00000000-0000 with addr tcp://10.110.1.8:4567 timed out, no messages seen in PT3S, socket stats: rtt: 0 rttvar: 250000 rto: 2000000 lost: 1 last_data_recv: 48332160 cwnd: 1 last_queued_since: 48633226476207 last_delivered_since: 48633226476207 send_queue_length: 0 send_queue_bytes: 0 (gmcast.peer_timeout)
percona_percona.3.4nfwet49xkaf@6    | 2024-06-26T09:34:49.338012+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] (97a651ce-b4b8, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection to peer 00000000-0000 with addr tcp://10.110.1.8:4567 timed out, no messages seen in PT3S, socket stats: rtt: 0 rttvar: 250000 rto: 2000000 lost: 1 last_data_recv: 48336660 cwnd: 1 last_queued_since: 48637727024505 last_delivered_since: 48637727024505 send_queue_length: 0 send_queue_bytes: 0 (gmcast.peer_timeout)
percona_percona.3.4nfwet49xkaf@6    | 2024-06-26T09:34:53.838506+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] (97a651ce-b4b8, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection to peer 00000000-0000 with addr tcp://10.110.1.8:4567 timed out, no messages seen in PT3S, socket stats: rtt: 0 rttvar: 250000 rto: 2000000 lost: 1 last_data_recv: 48341160 cwnd: 1 last_queued_since: 48642227528558 last_delivered_since: 48642227528558 send_queue_length: 0 send_queue_bytes: 0 (gmcast.peer_timeout)
percona_percona.3.4nfwet49xkaf@6    | 2024-06-26T09:34:57.839023+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] (97a651ce-b4b8, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection to peer 00000000-0000 with addr tcp://10.110.1.8:4567 timed out, no messages seen in PT3S, socket stats: rtt: 0 rttvar: 250000 rto: 2000000 lost: 1 last_data_recv: 48345160 cwnd: 1 last_queued_since: 48646228029586 last_delivered_since: 48646228029586 send_queue_length: 0 send_queue_bytes: 0 (gmcast.peer_timeout)
percona_percona.3.4nfwet49xkaf@6    | 2024-06-26T09:35:02.339742+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] (97a651ce-b4b8, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection to peer 00000000-0000 with addr tcp://10.110.1.8:4567 timed out, no messages seen in PT3S, socket stats: rtt: 0 rttvar: 250000 rto: 2000000 lost: 1 last_data_recv: 48349664 cwnd: 1 last_queued_since: 48650728755275 last_delivered_since: 48650728755275 send_queue_length: 0 send_queue_bytes: 0 (gmcast.peer_timeout)
percona_percona.3.4nfwet49xkaf@6    | 2024-06-26T09:35:06.840280+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] (97a651ce-b4b8, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection to peer 00000000-0000 with addr tcp://10.110.1.8:4567 timed out, no messages seen in PT3S, socket stats: rtt: 0 rttvar: 250000 rto: 2000000 lost: 1 last_data_recv: 48354164 cwnd: 1 last_queued_since: 48655229290789 last_delivered_since: 48655229290789 send_queue_length: 0 send_queue_bytes: 0 (gmcast.peer_timeout)
percona_percona.3.4nfwet49xkaf@6    | 2024-06-26T09:35:10.840851+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] (97a651ce-b4b8, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection to peer 00000000-0000 with addr tcp://10.110.1.8:4567 timed out, no messages seen in PT3S, socket stats: rtt: 0 rttvar: 250000 rto: 2000000 lost: 1 last_data_recv: 48358164 cwnd: 1 last_queued_since: 48659229864294 last_delivered_since: 48659229864294 send_queue_length: 0 send_queue_bytes: 0 (gmcast.peer_timeout)
percona_percona.3.4nfwet49xkaf@6    | 2024-06-26T09:35:15.341442+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] (97a651ce-b4b8, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection to peer 00000000-0000 with addr tcp://10.110.1.8:4567 timed out, no messages seen in PT3S, socket stats: rtt: 0 rttvar: 250000 rto: 2000000 lost: 1 last_data_recv: 48362664 cwnd: 1 last_queued_since: 48663730459120 last_delivered_since: 48663730459120 send_queue_length: 0 send_queue_bytes: 0 (gmcast.peer_timeout)
percona_percona.3.4nfwet49xkaf@6    | 2024-06-26T09:35:19.841996+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] (97a651ce-b4b8, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection to peer 00000000-0000 with addr tcp://10.110.1.8:4567 timed out, no messages seen in PT3S, socket stats: rtt: 0 rttvar: 250000 rto: 2000000 lost: 1 last_data_recv: 48367164 cwnd: 1 last_queued_since: 48668231010175 last_delivered_since: 48668231010175 send_queue_length: 0 send_queue_bytes: 0 (gmcast.peer_timeout)
percona_percona.3.4nfwet49xkaf@6    | 2024-06-26T09:35:24.342706+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] (97a651ce-b4b8, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection to peer 00000000-0000 with addr tcp://10.110.1.8:4567 timed out, no messages seen in PT3S, socket stats: rtt: 0 rttvar: 250000 rto: 2000000 lost: 1 last_data_recv: 48371664 cwnd: 1 last_queued_since: 48672731720374 last_delivered_since: 48672731720374 send_queue_length: 0 send_queue_bytes: 0 (gmcast.peer_timeout)
percona_percona.1.1qtirby8sooe@5    | 2024-06-26T09:35:26.593500+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] (e6fe01a0-a37f, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') reconnecting to 97a651ce-b4b7 (tcp://10.110.1.216:4567), attempt 600
percona_percona.3.4nfwet49xkaf@6    | 2024-06-26T09:35:28.343259+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] (97a651ce-b4b8, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection to peer 00000000-0000 with addr tcp://10.110.1.8:4567 timed out, no messages seen in PT3S, socket stats: rtt: 0 rttvar: 250000 rto: 2000000 lost: 1 last_data_recv: 48375668 cwnd: 1 last_queued_since: 48676732282195 last_delivered_since: 48676732282195 send_queue_length: 0 send_queue_bytes: 0 (gmcast.peer_timeout)
percona_percona.3.4nfwet49xkaf@6    | 2024-06-26T09:35:32.843742+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] (97a651ce-b4b8, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection to peer 00000000-0000 with addr tcp://10.110.1.8:4567 timed out, no messages seen in PT3S, socket stats: rtt: 0 rttvar: 250000 rto: 2000000 lost: 1 last_data_recv: 48380168 cwnd: 1 last_queued_since: 48681232755452 last_delivered_since: 48681232755452 send_queue_length: 0 send_queue_bytes: 0 (gmcast.peer_timeout)

In case it is relevant:
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:08.033521+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] GCache::RingBuffer initial scan...  0.0% (        0/134217752 bytes) complete.
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:08.033673+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] GCache::RingBuffer initial scan...100.0% (134217752/134217752 bytes) complete.
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:08.033703+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] Recovering GCache ring buffer: found gapless sequence 1-27
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:08.033835+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] GCache::RingBuffer unused buffers scan...  0.0% (      0/4076528 bytes) complete.
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:08.033901+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] GCache::RingBuffer unused buffers scan...100.0% (4076528/4076528 bytes) complete.
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:08.033928+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] Recovering GCache ring buffer: found 4/31 locked buffers
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:08.033952+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] Recovering GCache ring buffer: free space: 130141976/134217728
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:08.036593+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] Passing config to GCS: allocator.disk_pages_encryption = no; allocator.encryption_cache_page_size = 32K; allocator.encryption_cache_size = 16777216; base_dir = /var/lib/mysql/; base_host = 10.110.1.237; base_port = 4567; cert.log_conflicts = no; cert.optimistic_pa = no; debug = no; evs.auto_evict = 0; evs.delay_margin = PT1S; evs.delayed_keep_period = PT30S; evs.inactive_check_period = PT0.5S; evs.inactive_timeout = PT15S; evs.join_retrans_period = PT1S; evs.max_install_timeouts = 3; evs.send_window = 10; evs.stats_report_period = PT1M; evs.suspect_timeout = PT5S; evs.user_send_window = 4; evs.view_forget_timeout = PT24H; gcache.dir = /var/lib/mysql/; gcache.encryption = no; gcache.encryption_cache_page_size = 32K; gcache.encryption_cache_size = 16777216; gcache.freeze_purge_at_seqno = -1; gcache.keep_pages_count = 0; gcache.keep_pages_size = 0; gcache.mem_size = 0; gcache.name = galera.cache; gcache.page_size = 128M; gcache.recover = yes; gcache.size = 128M; gcomm.thread_prio = ; gcs.fc_auto_evict_threshold = 0.75; gcs.fc_auto_evict_window = 0; gcs.fc_debug = 0; gcs.fc_factor = 1.0; gcs.fc_limit = 100; gcs.fc_master_slave = no; gcs.fc_single_primary = no; gcs.max_packet_size = 64500; gcs.max_throttle = 0.25; gcs.recv_q_hard_limit = 9223372036854775807; gcs.recv_q_soft_limit = 0.25; gcs.sync_donor = no; gmcast.segment = 0; gmcast.version = 0; pc.announce_timeout = PT3S; pc.checksum = false; pc.ignore_quorum = false; pc.ignore_sb = false; pc.npvo = false; pc.recovery = true; pc.version = 0; pc.wait_prim = true; pc.wait_prim_timeout = PT30S; pc.wait_restored_prim_timeout = PT0S; pc.weight = 1; protonet.backend = asio; protonet.version = 0; repl.causal_read_timeout = PT30S; repl.commit_order = 3; repl.key_format = FLAT8; repl.max_ws_size = 2147483647; repl.proto_max = 11; socket.checksum = 2; socket.recv_buf_size = auto; socket.send_buf_size = auto;
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:08.049894+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] Service thread queue flushed.
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:08.050045+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] ####### Assign initial position for certification: ef7dae57-33b1-11ef-8fa0-b2e51da68967:27, protocol version: -1
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:08.050400+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [WSREP] Starting replication
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:08.050429+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] Connecting with bootstrap option: 0
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:08.050489+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] Setting GCS initial position to ef7dae57-33b1-11ef-8fa0-b2e51da68967:27
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:08.050689+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] protonet asio version 0
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:08.050823+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] Using CRC-32C for message checksums.
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:08.050879+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] backend: asio
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:08.051105+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] gcomm thread scheduling priority set to other:0
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:08.051541+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] Fail to access the file (/var/lib/mysql//gvwstate.dat) error (No such file or directory). It is possible if node is booting for first time or re-booting after a graceful shutdown
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:08.051566+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] Restoring primary-component from disk failed. Either node is booting for first time or re-booting after a graceful shutdown
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:08.051978+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] GMCast version 0
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:08.052387+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] (de2016a7-a4dd, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') listening at tcp://0.0.0.0:4567
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:08.052415+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] (de2016a7-a4dd, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') multicast: , ttl: 1
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:08.053607+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] EVS version 1
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:08.053894+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] gcomm: connecting to group 'percona', peer '10.110.1.228:'
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:09.055605+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] EVS version upgrade 0 -> 1
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:09.055722+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] PC protocol upgrade 0 -> 1
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:09.055996+03:00 0 [Warning] [MY-000000] [Galera] no nodes coming from prim view, prim not possible
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:09.056100+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] Current view of cluster as seen by this node
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | view (view_id(NON_PRIM,de2016a7-a4dd,1)
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | memb {
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    |         de2016a7-a4dd,0
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    |         }
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | joined {
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    |         }
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | left {
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    |         }
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | partitioned {
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    |         }
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | )
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:09.556371+03:00 0 [Warning] [MY-000000] [Galera] last inactive check more than PT1.5S (3*evs.inactive_check_period) ago (PT1.50286S), skipping check
percona_percona.2.zywef0zhu307@4    | 2024-06-26T15:16:10.370208+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] (edbc8a03-8172, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection to peer 00000000-0000 with addr tcp://10.110.1.228:4567 timed out, no messages seen in PT3S, socket stats: rtt: 0 rttvar: 250000 rto: 2000000 lost: 1 last_data_recv: 68857072 cwnd: 1 last_queued_since: 69157715676565 last_delivered_since: 69157715676565 send_queue_length: 0 send_queue_bytes: 0 (gmcast.peer_timeout)
percona_percona.2.zywef0zhu307@4    | 2024-06-26T15:16:10.870322+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] (edbc8a03-8172, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection to peer 00000000-0000 with addr tcp://10.110.1.229:4567 timed out, no messages seen in PT3S, socket stats: rtt: 0 rttvar: 250000 rto: 2000000 lost: 1 last_data_recv: 68857572 cwnd: 1 last_queued_since: 69158215786557 last_delivered_since: 69158215786557 send_queue_length: 0 send_queue_bytes: 0 (gmcast.peer_timeout)
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:11.057007+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] (de2016a7-a4dd, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection to peer 00000000-0000 with addr tcp://10.110.1.228:4567 timed out, no messages seen in PT3S, socket stats: rtt: 0 rttvar: 250000 rto: 2000000 lost: 1 last_data_recv: 69342044 cwnd: 1 last_queued_since: 69642697622679 last_delivered_since: 69642697622679 send_queue_length: 0 send_queue_bytes: 0 (gmcast.peer_timeout)
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:11.057386+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] announce period timed out (pc.announce_timeout)
percona_percona.2.zywef0zhu307@4    | 2024-06-26T15:16:14.370832+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] (edbc8a03-8172, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection to peer 00000000-0000 with addr tcp://10.110.1.228:4567 timed out, no messages seen in PT3S, socket stats: rtt: 0 rttvar: 250000 rto: 2000000 lost: 1 last_data_recv: 68861072 cwnd: 1 last_queued_since: 69161716301567 last_delivered_since: 69161716301567 send_queue_length: 0 send_queue_bytes: 0 (gmcast.peer_timeout)
percona_percona.2.zywef0zhu307@4    | 2024-06-26T15:16:14.870955+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] (edbc8a03-8172, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection to peer 00000000-0000 with addr tcp://10.110.1.229:4567 timed out, no messages seen in PT3S, socket stats: rtt: 0 rttvar: 250000 rto: 2000000 lost: 1 last_data_recv: 68861572 cwnd: 1 last_queued_since: 69162216420597 last_delivered_since: 69162216420597 send_queue_length: 0 send_queue_bytes: 0 (gmcast.peer_timeout)
percona_percona.2.zywef0zhu307@4    | 2024-06-26T15:16:18.371639+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] (edbc8a03-8172, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection to peer 00000000-0000 with addr tcp://10.110.1.228:4567 timed out, no messages seen in PT3S, socket stats: rtt: 0 rttvar: 250000 rto: 2000000 lost: 1 last_data_recv: 68865076 cwnd: 1 last_queued_since: 69165717105489 last_delivered_since: 69165717105489 send_queue_length: 0 send_queue_bytes: 0 (gmcast.peer_timeout)
percona_percona.2.zywef0zhu307@4    | 2024-06-26T15:16:18.871770+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] (edbc8a03-8172, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection to peer 00000000-0000 with addr tcp://10.110.1.229:4567 timed out, no messages seen in PT3S, socket stats: rtt: 0 rttvar: 250000 rto: 2000000 lost: 1 last_data_recv: 68865576 cwnd: 1 last_queued_since: 69166217225505 last_delivered_since: 69166217225505 send_queue_length: 0 send_queue_bytes: 0 (gmcast.peer_timeout)
percona_percona.2.zywef0zhu307@4    | 2024-06-26T15:16:22.372319+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] (edbc8a03-8172, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection to peer 00000000-0000 with addr tcp://10.110.1.228:4567 timed out, no messages seen in PT3S, socket stats: rtt: 0 rttvar: 250000 rto: 2000000 lost: 1 last_data_recv: 68869076 cwnd: 1 last_queued_since: 69169717763371 last_delivered_since: 69169717763371 send_queue_length: 0 send_queue_bytes: 0 (gmcast.peer_timeout)
percona_percona.2.zywef0zhu307@4    | 2024-06-26T15:16:26.373049+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] (edbc8a03-8172, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection to peer 00000000-0000 with addr tcp://10.110.1.227:4567 timed out, no messages seen in PT3S, socket stats: rtt: 0 rttvar: 250000 rto: 2000000 lost: 1 last_data_recv: 68873076 cwnd: 1 last_queued_since: 69173718510310 last_delivered_since: 69173718510310 send_queue_length: 0 send_queue_bytes: 0 (gmcast.peer_timeout)
percona_percona.2.zywef0zhu307@4    | 2024-06-26T15:16:26.873130+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] (edbc8a03-8172, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection to peer 00000000-0000 with addr tcp://10.110.1.228:4567 timed out, no messages seen in PT3S, socket stats: rtt: 0 rttvar: 250000 rto: 4000000 lost: 1 last_data_recv: 68873576 cwnd: 1 last_queued_since: 69174218596749 last_delivered_since: 69174218596749 send_queue_length: 0 send_queue_bytes: 0 (gmcast.peer_timeout)
percona_percona.2.zywef0zhu307@4    | 2024-06-26T15:16:30.373762+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] (edbc8a03-8172, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection to peer 00000000-0000 with addr tcp://10.110.1.227:4567 timed out, no messages seen in PT3S, socket stats: rtt: 0 rttvar: 250000 rto: 2000000 lost: 1 last_data_recv: 68877076 cwnd: 1 last_queued_since: 69177719220656 last_delivered_since: 69177719220656 send_queue_length: 0 send_queue_bytes: 0 (gmcast.peer_timeout)
percona_percona.2.zywef0zhu307@4    | 2024-06-26T15:16:30.873892+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] (edbc8a03-8172, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection to peer 00000000-0000 with addr tcp://10.110.1.228:4567 timed out, no messages seen in PT3S, socket stats: rtt: 0 rttvar: 250000 rto: 2000000 lost: 1 last_data_recv: 68877576 cwnd: 1 last_queued_since: 69178219359311 last_delivered_since: 69178219359311 send_queue_length: 0 send_queue_bytes: 0 (gmcast.peer_timeout)
percona_percona.2.zywef0zhu307@4    | 2024-06-26T15:16:34.874548+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] (edbc8a03-8172, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection to peer 00000000-0000 with addr tcp://10.110.1.228:4567 timed out, no messages seen in PT3S, socket stats: rtt: 0 rttvar: 250000 rto: 2000000 lost: 1 last_data_recv: 68881576 cwnd: 1 last_queued_since: 69182220002193 last_delivered_since: 69182220002193 send_queue_length: 0 send_queue_bytes: 0 (gmcast.peer_timeout)
percona_percona.2.zywef0zhu307@4    | 2024-06-26T15:16:38.375201+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] (edbc8a03-8172, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection to peer 00000000-0000 with addr tcp://10.110.1.227:4567 timed out, no messages seen in PT3S, socket stats: rtt: 0 rttvar: 250000 rto: 2000000 lost: 1 last_data_recv: 68885076 cwnd: 1 last_queued_since: 69185720669781 last_delivered_since: 69185720669781 send_queue_length: 0 send_queue_bytes: 0 (gmcast.peer_timeout)
percona_percona.2.zywef0zhu307@4    | 2024-06-26T15:16:38.875404+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] (edbc8a03-8172, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection to peer 00000000-0000 with addr tcp://10.110.1.228:4567 timed out, no messages seen in PT3S, socket stats: rtt: 0 rttvar: 250000 rto: 2000000 lost: 1 last_data_recv: 68885576 cwnd: 1 last_queued_since: 69186220826060 last_delivered_since: 69186220826060 send_queue_length: 0 send_queue_bytes: 0 (gmcast.peer_timeout)
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:41.063195+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] PC protocol downgrade 1 -> 0
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:41.063266+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] Current view of cluster as seen by this node
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | view ((empty))
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:41.064569+03:00 0 [ERROR] [MY-000000] [Galera] failed to open gcomm backend connection: 110: failed to reach primary view (pc.wait_prim_timeout): 110 (Connection timed out)
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    |          at /mnt/jenkins/workspace/pxc80-autobuild-RELEASE/test/rpmbuild/BUILD/Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-8.0.36/percona-xtradb-cluster-galera/gcomm/src/pc.cpp:connect():176
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:41.064608+03:00 0 [ERROR] [MY-000000] [Galera] /mnt/jenkins/workspace/pxc80-autobuild-RELEASE/test/rpmbuild/BUILD/Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-8.0.36/percona-xtradb-cluster-galera/gcs/src/gcs_core.cpp:gcs_core_open():219: Failed to open backend connection: -110 (Connection timed out)
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:42.066059+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] gcomm: terminating thread
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:42.066127+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] gcomm: joining thread
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:42.066844+03:00 0 [ERROR] [MY-000000] [Galera] /mnt/jenkins/workspace/pxc80-autobuild-RELEASE/test/rpmbuild/BUILD/Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-8.0.36/percona-xtradb-cluster-galera/gcs/src/gcs.cpp:gcs_open():1880: Failed to open channel 'percona' at 'gcomm://10.110.1.228': -110 (Connection timed out)
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:42.066881+03:00 0 [ERROR] [MY-000000] [Galera] gcs connect failed: Connection timed out
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:42.066904+03:00 0 [ERROR] [MY-000000] [WSREP] Provider/Node (gcomm://10.110.1.228) failed to establish connection with cluster (reason: 7)
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:42.066923+03:00 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:42.067017+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-010120] [Server] Binlog end
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:42.067169+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-010733] [Server] Shutting down plugin 'daemon_keyring_proxy_plugin'
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:42.067353+03:00 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.36-28.1)  Percona XtraDB Cluster (GPL), Release rel28, Revision bfb687f, WSREP version 26.1.4.3.
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:42.069343+03:00 0 [ERROR] [MY-010065] [Server] Failed to shutdown components infrastructure.
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:42.069879+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] dtor state: CLOSED
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:42.070260+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] MemPool(TrxHandleSlave): hit ratio: 0, misses: 0, in use: 0, in pool: 0
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:42.073726+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] apply mon: entered 0
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:42.077172+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] apply mon: entered 0
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:42.080705+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] apply mon: entered 0
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:42.081069+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] cert index usage at exit 0
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:42.081106+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] cert trx map usage at exit 0
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:42.081133+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] deps set usage at exit 0
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:42.081161+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] avg deps dist 0
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:42.081180+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] avg cert interval 0
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:42.081237+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] cert index size 0
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:42.081368+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] Service thread queue flushed.
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:42.081430+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] wsdb trx map usage 0 conn query map usage 0
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:42.081767+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] MemPool(LocalTrxHandle): hit ratio: 0, misses: 0, in use: 0, in pool: 0
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:42.081951+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] Shifting CLOSED -> DESTROYED (TO: 0)
percona_percona.1.jc7t3d4h8qp2@5    | 2024-06-26T15:16:42.084365+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] Flushing memory map to disk...
percona_percona.2.zywef0zhu307@4    | 2024-06-26T15:16:42.376012+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] (edbc8a03-8172, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection to peer 00000000-0000 with addr tcp://10.110.1.227:4567 timed out, no messages seen in PT3S, socket stats: rtt: 0 rttvar: 250000 rto: 2000000 lost: 1 last_data_recv: 68889080 cwnd: 1 last_queued_since: 69189721462061 last_delivered_since: 69189721462061 send_queue_length: 0 send_queue_bytes: 0 (gmcast.peer_timeout)
percona_percona.2.zywef0zhu307@4    | 2024-06-26T15:16:42.876093+03:00 0 [Note] [MY-000000] [Galera] (edbc8a03-8172, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection to peer 00000000-0000 with addr tcp://10.110.1.228:4567 timed out, no messages seen in PT3S, socket stats: rtt: 0 rttvar: 250000 rto: 2000000 lost: 1 last_data_recv: 68889580 cwnd: 1 last_queued_since: 69190221559906 last_delivered_since: 69190221559906 send_queue_length: 0 send_queue_bytes: 0 (gmcast.peer_timeout)

I can’t figure out why it worked first day and now percona services does not find each other anymore.
Can some one help me resolve this issue?
It should fully recover after stack restart, or power shut down of all servers.

You say there was initial connectivity and given the compose yaml this implies the overlay network is functioning and healthy and there is no interference from firewalls.
This implies that the reconnection attempts are simply going to the wrong IPs so I am going to hazard a guess here and say that percona uses etcd as a service discovery mechanism, and the nodes store their IP addresses there for clustering.
When docker (swarm) restarts service tasks, a new container with a new IP is generated each time. This means each time a service replica is restarted for any reason the pool of nodes grows to include the new container IP, and the old IP that no longer works, hangs around.
With no specific knowledge of Percona, with other products (hashicorp vault and consul) I work around this by assigning each replica a unique, but sticky, hostname - Assuming percona can be coerced into using hostnames for service discovery then:
The hostname of a container is normally the container id so it continually changes which is not good. However we can use dockers service template syntax to assign a unique hostname to each service task. Docker adds these as unique network aliases, so percona instances can address each other as "percona1", "percona2", "percona3". etc.
services:
  percona:
    hostname: percona{{.Task.Slot}}

You will need to fiddle with the service discovery settings to ensure the names rather than container ips are used.
